# Using PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with two property grids. 
The `SelectedObject` property of the first grid is set to contain the `item` object. And the second one is set to `item.Test`;

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Item item = new Item();
    propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = item;
    propertyGrid2.SelectedObject = item.Test;
}
```

This is the structure of the `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    List<int> _test = new List<int>();

    public List<int> Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set { _test = value; }
    }
}
```

[image]
And here how the UI looks like:

My question is,  from the grid 1, why is the `Test` property is being displayed in a Int32 Collection Editor while in the grid 2 it appears different? They are pointing at the same object right? How can I make grid 2 to display `Test` property in a Int32 Collection Editor?

Answer (score 0):

In the first window, you are displaying an object that *has* a member called `Test`, that *is* the collection; in the second window you are display the collection itself - the collection doesn't know the name.

`Test` is **not** the name of the collection; it is the name of the property which (when accessed) *returns* the collection.

In code terms (illustrative only, note - the real stuff here is all `PropertyDescriptor` etc):

```
var obj = new PropertyTest(); // the outer object
```

Now, this object has a property called `Test`, and given "Test", we can obtain the collection:

```
var collection = obj.Test; // at this point, we have all three
```

However, from the variable `collection` (and indeed from the object *referenced* by the variable `collection`) it is **completely impossible** to get the string "Test". And indeed, there could actually be zero, one, or any number of properties on any object or set of objects which expose this collection.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I want grid 2 to display the content of the property Test (like the one displayed in the Int32 collection Editor), how would I do it? Is it possible?